# Big locale files in rails, is it ok?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-i18n

I couldn't *really* find an answer for this on the internet. I am currently developing a relatively big web application in Rails. And my locale file is growing rapidly.

My question is, does it matter if my locale file gets really big? If it doesn't matter, how does Rails handle this? If it does, what would be a good solution to this? I found in the rails documentations that you can name your files respectively to their language e.g. [`index.en.html.erb`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#localized-views). But that would mean I'd have to edit each view for each language individually when a change has to be made.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Locales are loaded into memory when the server is started (not on every request). Rails handles all locales internally as one big nested hash. Therefore Rails does not care if there are one big or many small locale files.

What you need to consider: What works well for you. I had to work with an app with ~ 5000 locales once. I was very happy that they were organized into one folder for each language and splited into multiple files: One for every model or controller. The locales were clearly arranged and easy to find. Later we used a webservice to maintain the locales (webtranslateit.com) what also helped a lot when working with external (not technical) translators.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to break up your locales file into separate files.  More info:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#organization-of-locale-files

Comment: I did see that, but when you look below to how that is set up in the application.rb, it looks like it's still all being loaded at once. So if i'm not mistaken the benefit is just that it's not stored in a single file.

Comment: Are you worried that the entire file has to be read for every request?

Comment: Not the file perse, I am worried that a lot of translations are loaded while they are not required by the view.

Comment: I believe that the translations are loaded into memory when the server starts in production, it's not loaded on every request.